# How to burn rEfit .cdr or .dmg in Ubuntu or Windows?

Tags: ubuntu, burning, dmg-image, refit, cd-r

I don't have Mac OS X installed on my MacBook Pro, but I have Ubuntu and Windows.

I was following [this website's instructions](http://mac.linux.be/content/single-boot-linux-without-delay) to boot faster into Ubuntu without a 30 second delay. However I can't even burn a rEfit CDR image. Do you know how to burn it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Installing rEFIt](http://refit.sourceforge.net/doc/c1s1_install.html) - at the [sourceforge rEFIt page](http://refit.sourceforge.net/) has a link to the [**CD Burning Instructions**](http://refit.sourceforge.net/doc/c1s5_burning.html).
<sup>You may also want to read this [TripleBoot via BootCamp](http://wiki.onmac.net/index.php/Triple_Boot_via_BootCamp#Booting_your_mac_via_rEFIt) page at the [onmac Wiki](http://wiki.onmac.net/index.php/Main_Page).</sup>

---

**Update** on your comments.

- Extensions `.dmg` and `.cdr` are used for [Disk Images created on Mac](http://www.ehow.com/how_2093946_create-disk-image-mac-osx.html)
- I suspect the Windows/Linux target file '`rEFIt-0.14.cdr.gz`' is a gzipped ISO
  Try the following,

  - **`gunzip`** the '`rEFIt-0.14.cdr.gz`' to '`rEFIt-0.14.cdr`' and,
  - Rename '`rEFIt-0.14.cdr`' to '`rEFIt-0.14.iso`'

<sup>If you don't have '`gunzip`' handy, use [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/).</sup>

---

**Update2**:

- The file is just under 7MB so I downloaded it and tried some of the steps.
  The `gunzipped` file shows these details on my windows machine,

```
$ file rEFIt-0.14.cdr
rEFIt-0.14.cdr: Apple Partition data block size: 512,  
first type: Apple_partition_map,  
name: Apple, number of blocks: 63,  
second type: Apple_HFS, name: disk image,  
number of blocks: 40896,
```

- Since its a `.gz` which opened properly for both of us, chances of it being corrupted are none (unless its corrupted at the source).
- The sourceforege description very clearly says this `.cdr` should be processed as an ISO. However, this file detail of Apple partition map surprises me a bit. I do not have a Mac handy

  - let me see if I or someone here can figure things out
- One direction to check is: [How to burn a mac-disc on windows?](http://discussions.info.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2342915&tstart=149)

---

**Oh!**, There is something very obvious missing here...
These are bug reports from their sourceforge track!

- [Your "CD Burn Instructions" are a pile of BS - ID: 2995039](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=2995039&group_id=161917&atid=821764), Open
- [A CDR file is not an ISO file - ID: 2987447](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=2987447&group_id=161917&atid=821764), Closed as Invalid,
  with the following note,

> If your CD recording software refuses to burn the image because of the file
>   extension, rename the file. If it refuses to burn the image because of the
>   file contents, file a bug against the CD recording software.
>   **The distributed image file is a perfectly normal sector-by-sector image like
>   any other "ISO" file**. It does not contain an ISO9660 file system; instead
>   it contains an Apple Partition Map and a HFS+ file system. That's what is
>   needed to make Mac systems boot from it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I still can't figure out how to burn a .cdr file. What program should I use? I've tried Nero and AcetonicISO but they didn't recognize this file type. I've also tried to mount the .dmg file under ubuntu, but it gave me some kind of error.

Comment: thanks again. My hard drive capacity is not big, so I don't want to triple boot. 

CD burning instructions say "Ask your favourite burning software to burn “rEFIt-0.14.cdr” as a “ISO image” or “disk image”." None of my favorite software recognize a .cdr format.

Comment: thanks for the update. renaming to iso does not work. But anyway, why why wouldn't the authors of rEFIT make an iso image instead of cdr?

Comment: Well, I am guessing that the authors made it on a Mac (http://www.ehow.com/how_2093946_create-disk-image-mac-osx.html).

Answer (score 3):

Worked for me on my Ubuntu box: renamed to .iso, then opened K3B, chose 'more options' -> 'burn image' and select the wanted file. First K3B says it's not a valid, but then I chose 'plain data image' on the 'image type' menu on the right and it would just burn it fine!
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Brasero on ubuntu appears to burn this file properly. As noted by one of the other commentors, this is not a windowsy ISO. Because it doesn't contain an ISO9660 filesystem, many burning software programs complain and even refuse to do anything with it. Brasero on ubuntu worked without a hickup. I simply renamed to .iso, right clicked and selected "Open with Brasero". It then brought up the normal cd/dvd burning dialogue and started burning the DVD. Note that because it's only a few megs, it still has to write a gig or so of data to work properly as a DVD. (I don't have any CDs handy.)

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this problem as well. I got the white screen with blinking grey folder/question mark on my macbook pro a1286 and needed to know whether or not it was the hard drive or logic board that was fried. I run Linux Mint on my lenovo p500 and I needed to burn the refit.014.cdr file to a cd to try and boot from the disk drive to see whether the hard drive was good. I used Archive Manager to extract the cdr.gz file, then selected open with other applications and chose brasero. I changed the file to .iso and it worked perfectly burning to the disk.