# How to burn a .cdr file using Fedora?

Tags: linux, macos, burning, cd-r

My Macbook crashed so I don't have access to DiskUtility to burn an OSX .CDR dvd.  I have booted into Fedora with a LiveCD, but I cannot seem to find anything that will allow me to burn the cdr file to a dvd.

I've tried renaming the .cdr file to a .iso and burning it with brasero, but I just ended up with a coaster.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to burn rEfit .cdr or .dmg in Ubuntu or Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/140976/how-to-burn-refit-cdr-or-dmg-in-ubuntu-or-windows)

Comment: Hope this helps you http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialCDBurn.html

Comment: @soandos Thanks; I already saw that link, but the posted solutions were discussing dmg files.  I didn't want to clutter or hijack the thread so started a different one specific for CDR files.

Comment: @V413HAV My problem isn't how to burn something in Linux.  It's more a question of what understands the CDR format.  I tried to rename it to an ISO, but it didn't seem to work.  Nor was I able to mount it as I would a normal ISO, so I wonder if CDR format is something specific/unique.

Comment: You can't just rename the extension and mount files, extensions are containers which hold specific type of formatting say .jpg files are used majority for images, but .png files are used specifically to maintain transparency in images, so same way even .iso has its own properties, and .cdr has its own. Changing the extension won't work bro!

Comment: @V413HAV I didn't expect as much, but keep finding several posts that seem to indicate that was the correct process.  Consequently, I'm still wondering how one can burn a cdr file to DVD if you aren't on a Mac?  Even a windows solution at this point would be acceptable, but I naturally assumed that it would be easier to find a linux solution instead.

Comment: I've managed to get the .cdr file burned using [TransMac](http://www.asy.com/sharetm.htm) on windows, but I'm still trying to figure out if there is a way in Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you have the actual .cdr image, try feeding it to cdrecord/wodim as a regular ISO. The [instructions](http://refit.sourceforge.net/doc/c1s5_burning.html) on the rEfit SF page say that it should work and cdrecord doesn't care about extensions.

```
cdrecord -v speed=XX dev=dev -data image.cdr
```

Replace XX with the desired speed and set the dev value to your DVD device.

Comment: Thanks, will try that.  Ran out of DVDs at the moment, so might take me a bit before I pick up more.